# STM32 on Registers Setting Up PLL, WWDG fault, Parameter/Setup Issue

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, pll, cmsis

STM32F746-Disco, Win 10, Cube 1.8.0; CMSIS-only (no HAL). C.

I've been messing around with STM32F746 and learning to do various stuff directly via registers (interrupts, dma no problem). I left configuring clock for the better days and was using default 16MHz HSI until today.

Better days have come. I've decided to go full 216MHz from 25MHz crystal with PLL. As usual, covered myself head to toe with documentation. Here is my code:

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"

int main(void)
{
    rcc_setup();
    gpio_setup();
    while(1){
        blink_ld1();
    }
}
```

part of rcc.c:

```
void rcc_init(void) {

    //enable HSE
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON;
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY)); //wait while hardware signals HSE is stable

    //configure AHB/APB clocks
    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1; //AHB Prescaler 1
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV4; //APB1 Prescaler 4
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV2; //APB2 Prescaler 2

    //configure PLL
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON; //Enable PLL
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY)); //wait while hardware signals PLL is OK

    RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE; //PLL/PLL2S source = HSE
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= 25U << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos; //PLLM 25
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= 432U << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos; //PLLN 432
    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP; //PLLP 2
    
    //Set System Clock to PLL
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL; // System Clock Mux: Select PLL as system clock
    while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != (RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL)); //wait until PLL is established as system clock
}
```

`rcc_init()` is literally the first thing `rcc_setup()` does.

It crashes with "WWDG interrupt infinite loop" if and only if I execute `RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;`. Otherwise, runs correctly.

As I was debugging, I decided to put a breakpoint exactly where my code breaks to look at the PLL registers and make sure the values I set are OK. And they're clearly not.
`RCC_PLLCFGR` is all wrong. I commented out all the code that modifies it. No change to values. So the register is at reset value. And I don't understand why.

Also, I tried commenting out APB/AHB prescaler modifications. No change (and it still works with new prescalers as long as system clock is from HSI).

I checked all AHB1ENR and APB's in case I forgot to activate the clock to something. Doesn't seem to be the case.

What did I miss?

**EDIT1:**

I swapped PLL parameter initialization (25 and 432) and PLL activation. Now the data in the register is changed from reset value. PLLM is correct. PLLN is NOT correct - not 432. Tinkering on. Mini-Edit. Wrote HEX value of 432. Still same fault.

**EDIT2:**

I went full pen and paper and manually calculated every single bit of the register, taking into account its reset value and bits that aren't supposed to be changed.

RCC_PLLCFGR reset value is `0x2400 3010`
I did `RCC->PLLCFGR = 0x29406C19;` This puts correct values into the correct places, triple checked with debugger and on paper. Same issue.

HAL library enables power for PWR peripheral. I read its part in the reference manual and found no connection to clock speeds. Can it be related or has nothing to do with it?

Also, I don't know why it writes that it fires window watchdog interrupt. There has never been a single program that used it on the disco board, absolutely certain. I think it jumps there due to clock error.

**EDIT3:**
I examined how auto-generated code uses HAL and initializes 216MHz. All PLL values are the same, but it also enables PWR peripheral and sets Overdrive and Overdrive switching. So I did functionally exactly the same as HAL, and I see no changes.

In the rcc_init function now after HSE enable I have the following:

```
//enable PWR peripheral
    volatile uint32_t temp;
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN;
    temp = RCC->APB1ENR & RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN;
    (void) temp; //waste cycles until activated
    PWR->CR1 |= PWR_CR1_VOS; //explicit default value for internal voltage regulator
    (void) temp; //waste cycles until activated
    PWR->CR1 |= PWR_CR1_ODEN;
    while (!(PWR->CSR1 & PWR_CSR1_ODRDY)); //wait while overdrive gets ready
    PWR->CR1 |= PWR_CR1_ODSWEN; //enable overdrive switching
    while (!(PWR->CSR1 & PWR_CSR1_ODSWRDY)); //wait while overdrive gets ready
```

Double checked register values, they're all set correctcly for overdrive. I even went so far as to debugging the CubeMX generated code and literally screenshotting RCC and PWR registers.

RCC:
CR - identical to the bit
PLLCFGR - identical to the bit
CFGR - identical to the bit

PWR:
CR1 - identical to the bit
CSR1 - identical to the bit
CR2 - identical to the bit
CSR2 - identical to the bit

Comment: Are you ORing the 432 value to the register, or writing it?

Comment: Obviously ORing since I have other parts of the register to write to. How could that be a problem?

Comment: Note that you are trying to operate at the extreme limit of the chip, any deviation in your crystal frequency puts you out of bounds.  Try a PLL rate that's say 98% of max instead of the absolute highest possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's default value of all STMicroelectronics provided examples. And they always work flawlessly

Comment: When using the PLL you also need to control PLLQ to keep the output in range.

Comment: Even if I'm not using any peripherals using it? And never activate any peripherals that get PLLQ clock?

Comment: Are you using some bootloader?  Because if this is the first code that executes, it will not be possible to get a watchdog interrupt because the watchdog is not enabled.   So I suspect that some other code is running first and leaving your chip in an modified configuration which you aren't accounting for.  Just one example -- the bootloader might have enabled the PLL, so you should explicitly disable it, and wait for it to stop, before changing its configuration.

Comment: Nope. It's a totally 100% blank project that starts with empty main file and nothing else. I even have to add register definition files and compiler-specific headers manually. Upload via built-in ST-Link. Yeah, the fact that out of nowhere a watchdog came up surprised me too. Maybe I accidentally jump somewhere in memory due to some fault or something.

Comment: A-ha!  Now I understand why the debugger told you you ended up in the watchdog fault handler.  The interrupt vector table uses a different name for each fault handler, but the template-generated project defines a weak symbol for each which aliases to a single infinite loop function.  So when you landed there, the debugger tried to do a reverse lookup from instruction address to function name, and that lookup was ambiguous.  Unfortunately it showed you the wrong name.

Comment: You were actually handling a bus fault, but the bus fault handler and watchdog handler were mapped to the same function via the weak symbols.

Comment: Well the debugging explicitly said "WWDG fault" (not function in the but in the debugging function tree on the left where it lists how functions call other functions - main->rcc_setup->rcc_init->wwdg_fault), but your definitely right about that. I will spend some time reading deeper about this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into CubeMX generated code again and examined line by line. I did everything right, except that I didn't set Flash latency! One and only line of code! And it worked! Since I have next to no experience with Flash yet, I took CubeMX-generated Flash latency value. Got some reading to do now. But for now, it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are assuming the register reset value is 0, but it's 0x24003010.

You can't just go ORing the bits with new N/M values and expect the values to be correct.

Comment: alright now this is actually a valid point. I will nullify the bits before ORing the right thing and will get back with it tomorrow. Somehow I saw the non-zero reset value when debugging and it simply didn't even occur to me for whatever reason.

Comment: I have manually written PLLCFGR value. Literally pen and paper, every bit.  RCC->PLLCFGR = 0x29406C19; Checked in the debugger, all values are correct (again pen and paper). Same problem. What am I missing urgh

Comment: Unfortunately, I have identical register content, and still doesn't work (more in edit)

Comment: What else have you done except boosted the frequency? Set the internal voltage regulator to high enough voltage to run CPU core at max speed? Set the flash prefetching to run at max speed? Set AHB and APB bus system clock divisors to run at their respective maximum speeds?

Comment: I left internal voltage regulators at default (as it is in CubeMX code). I don't entirely understand the whole purpose of that regulator and why my code ran without it from HSI. Also, I have no idea how prefetching works, I'm not that deep into it yet. And yes, I did set AHB and APB dividers. I've solved it. Edited it in. Compared CubeMX and my code side by side in terms of what they do. Obviously mine is 1/10th long. Thank you for your participation!

Answer (score 1):

The reference manual says (section 5.2.3 "PLL")

> Since **the main-PLL configuration parameters cannot be changed once PLL is enabled**, it is  recommended to configure PLL before enabling it (selection of the HSI or HSE oscillator as  PLL clock source, and configuration of division factors M, N, P, and Q).

Your code is trying to change the parameters while the PLL is running.

After you do

```
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON; //Enable PLL
while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY)); //wait while hardware signals PLL is OK
```

it is totally forbidden to do

```
RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE; //PLL/PLL2S source = HSE
RCC->PLLCFGR |= 25U << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos; //PLLM 25
RCC->PLLCFGR |= 432U << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos; //PLLN 432
RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP; //PLLP 2
```

Swap those two blocks and try again (also be sure to overwrite the whole register as @Justme pointed out and not rely on the previous configuration).